# How to build ITK project without cmake?

Tags: cmake, itk

How to build an ITK project without cmakelist.txt?

I have built ITK binaries with cmake and I have included all header files and libs in visual studio project but imagefilereader object is throwing exception,  is there any reason for it?

Comment: You probably did not register the io factories. http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/community/2014-April/001989.html

Comment: http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/FAQ#Why_can.27t_I_read_any_image_files.3F_or_Why_am_I_getting_the_exception_message:_.22There_are_no_registered_IO_factories..22.3F